# Send JSONdata from one view controller to another with segue perform method

Tags: ios

I have three view controller named Login, `HomeviewController` and `UserProfileController`. The landing homepage is `HomeViewController`. There is a `UIButton` named Login from where user will go to Login Controller. After giving UserId and Password, the user will be redirected to the homepage with credentials such as username, address, phoneNo and Email using JSON parsing.

I want to transfer that that data to `HomeViewController` and from HomeViewController there is a another button Profile. After clicking that button all data get set to `UITextField` of `UserProfileController`.

Comment: You can do it in different way, by calling delegate, completion handler or by setting some property. Show your code so we can give you some better suggestion.

Comment: simple, u need to transfer the json response value from one view controller to another view controller,correct

Comment: can u show ur sample json response, i give the answer for u

Answer (score 0):

You should implement prepareForSegue method and set some property in `destinationviewcontroller`.
Consider you have property named `jsonData` in `destinationViewController` then you can do this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   ViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
   destination.jsonData = self.jsonData;
}
```

You can modify this code as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
            MyViewController *mycontroller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            mycontroller.myProperty1 = jsonData;

        }
    }
```

How to call prepareForSegue. you must call below method it automatically call prepareForSegue method

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:sender];
}
```